# How to import multiple Excel columns into single SQL Server column?

Tags: sql-server, excel

We import a lot of data files (mostly Excel, sometimes CSV) from different sources into SQL Server databases. The data files have some common fields (name, address, etc.) and usually other fields - some we need/use and some that we don't need.

How could I import all the data in a file - inserting the common/required fields into the relevant columns but also merging the other remaining columns into a single column (text or varchar(max))? Is this possible? I don't mind what version of Excel/SQL Server.

So I might receive a source file such as

```
FirstName, LastName, AddressLine1, City, ColumnE, ColumnF, DateColumn, ColumnH
```

And this is stored in the SQL Server as

```
FirstName nvarchar(25)
LastName nvarchar(25)
AddressLine1 nvarchar(50)
City nvarchar(30)
OtherData nvarchar(max)
```

Of course the OtherData column needs to contain some delimiter to identify the Excel columns imported.

We only need to use the "common" columns, but when we export the data (which typically is only a subset of the original rows) we could more easily include the *OtherData* than creating customised tables for every different data file or merging back with Excel.

---

EDIT: I can achieve this by adding lots of extra columns to the data-file that act as a custom delimiter, then use BULK INSERT, but that's quite time-consuming.

Comment: How specifically are you importing the data? Are you using SSIS or BULK Insert or what?

Comment: Usually SSIS (or the import wizard) - most of the time it's a brand new data file from a new source (different client) and we either ignore a lot of the "other data" or we create a table specifically for this data file. The "other data" is not required for our tasks but we often need to stitch this back together when returning to the client. I'm wondering if there's a simpler way than creating sometimes 30-50 extra redundant columns to import to or the hoops we jump through with Excel after.

Answer (score 0):

As a rough idea, if you know the tab names in excel, you can use C# and the OLE DB/JET 12 driver to read the data into a dataset (basically SELECT * FROM [tabname]). CSV can be loaded much simpler. At that point, it's a matter of punching it into the database.

I miht be able to scratch out some psuedocode this evening if you're interested in that sort of approach.

Comment: is your approach to grab everything into memory (select * from [tabname]) - then you identify the common columns and merge the remainder into a single "blob" ?

Comment: I was assuming I'd have a predefined list of columns that were the common ones but otherwise, that'd be my general approach.